# Vista mysql , datos duplicados

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una vista en mysql que me guarde un cuestionario de preguntas y respuestas.
El detalle esta en que 1 pregunta puede tener mas de 1 respuesta como opción.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo hago una consulta a toda la vista obviamente obtendré preguntas duplicadas.

- La idea es mostrar en una vista web (1 pregunta - N respuestas)
- Existe alguna función en php o como seria la lógica para obtener este resultado

  **1. ¿Cuál debería ser el nivel de estudios de mi candidato?**

  ```
  - a. Secundaria completa
  - b. Estudios universitarios truncos
  - c. Estudios universitarios completos
  - e. Carrera Técnica
  ```

  **2.¿Cuál debe ser la experiencia laboral de mi candidato ideal?**

  ```
     - a. Administración de empresas
     - b. Militar
  ```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Sacando el problema inicial de que esa tabla esta mal (no esta normalizada, y normalizarla solucionaria todos tus problemas), porque buscas una funcion de php, cuando esto se soluciona con un group by en la base de datos?

Comment: También sería más lógico tener las respuestas y preguntas separas en tablas diferentes. Así podrías consultar la pregunta 1, y obtener las respuestas con ese id padre....

Comment: gracias por las recomendaciones, claro seria mas fácil hacerlo por separado pero es lo que me dieron yo no hice esa tabla, de igual forma llegue a solucionarlo gracias :)